# How to change the CSS apply order

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

See below screen grab, I want to make the `.navbar-account > li > a` as the active one. But by default it's disabled and active one is `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a`.  Due to this my font color doesn't change as red. I cannot put `!important` as it affects another page. So somehow I want to enable the `.navbar-account > li > a` in the `slid-in-menu.css`.

[image]

Comment: You could load `slide-in-menu.css` after `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: The classic hack--not recommended--is `.navbar-account.navbar-account > li > a`.

Comment: Either what is mentioned in the first comment (or) increase the specificity of the selector in slide-in-menu.css (like `body .navbar-default .navbar-account > li > a`. Can't you modify the contents of that file?

Comment: @SumnerEvans   yes, it is already after the `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @Harry  this one works well. Can you explain me how to read this? sometimes I have seen like write multiple selectors close together without space. like `body.navbar-default.navbar-account > li>a`

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the selector that is present within the bootstrap.min.css file has more specificity than the one that is present in slide-in-menu.css and hence that one wins.

Specificity is a very important thing because we can always have the same element being targeted by multiple selectors (like in this case) and during such times, the User Agents use the specificity of the selectors to determine which one would eventually win and get applied to the element.

As per [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
>
> The specificity is based only on the form of the selector. In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

For the selector `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a`, the specificity is 022 because it has two class selectors and two element type (`li`, `a`) selectors as part of it.

Whereas the selector `.navbar-account > li > a` has a specificity of only 021 because it only has 1 class selector and two element type selectors as part of it.

So, the key to overriding the properties specified within the bootstrap selector is to use a selector that is more specific than the bootstrap one. If we change the selector to `body .navbar-default .navbar-account > li a`, the selector's specificity becomes 023 (higher than bootstrap selector) because now it has 2 class selectors and 3 element type selectors and so it wins.

Changing the selector this way would not cause any other problems elsewhere also because `body` is always the parent for all elements and `.navbar-default` is the parent for `.navbar-account`.

**Note:** We could just use `.navbar-default .navbar-account > li a` (without the `body`) also but its specificity is 022, which is the same as the bootstrap selector and hence there is no guarantee that it will always get applied. (*This was written before I saw [this comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027163/how-to-change-the-css-apply-order/36028105#comment59705557_36027163). If the slide-in-menu.css is always loaded after bootstrap.min.css then this alone would also suffice.*)

Also, as I had mentioned in my comment to [Scott Marcus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36027230/2606013), if you want the bootstrap styles to be **overridden only for one page** then his answer has the best approach. The approach mentioned in my answer will override in all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-define that style in the particular page:

```
 <style>
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a { . . .}
 </style>
```

The local page style will override the linked one, but only affect the one page.

By the way, here is an excellent resource for determining which selector is more specific than another:  https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: You've got a valid point too. If it should override the bootstrap css only for that page alone then putting it inside the `<style>` tag of that page makes a lot more sense. Upvoted :)

Comment: @Harry That's the whole reason why we use page level stylesheets. To provide page-specific instructions that should override similar instructions from external stylesheets. IMO All the answers above are not correct because they will affect all pages and the OP said he didn't want that.

Comment: No, OP didn't really say they want to affect **only one page**. They said this - *I cannot put !important as it affects another page*. For all we know, they may want this style to be applied to x group pages but not y group. They never said anything about that.

Comment: For example, consider there is a `.nav.navbar-account.navbar-account2 > li > a`  (which is supposed to apply in another page with `.navbar-account2` class also on same element). If an `!important` is added, it would override that also which a higher specificity selector would not. There could be n reasons why a `!important` will affect other pages.

Comment: @Harry Technically, you are right, but I strongly suspect that your assessment is not correct for the OP because what you are describing is just another form of specificity.  My solution doesn't rely on any hacks -- just the basic way CSS rules cascade.

Comment: I can't comment on which one of us is correct but I go by [OP's comment under the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027163/how-to-change-the-css-apply-order/36027230#comment59706029_36027163). You may want to have a look at it :)

Comment: I don't see how that infers anything but your suggestion worked for him. But, as I say that solution is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Well, my suggestion working for him is IMO proof that he didn't want it applied for **only one page**. And, increasing specificity by attaching extra classes or elements is most definitely not a hack. (Not going to continue this further, will leave it to OP to decide what suits them. They had asked to explain the concept which was the primary purpose of my answer anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the freedom to change the CSS in 'slid-in-menu.css', then the following code illustrates the modification in the same CSS file (considering your existing HTML DOM and the classes applied):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-account {
     /* apply whichever CSS style you want to apply */
 }
```

Explanation:

> The CSS follows a hierarchy in which the former CSS applied was getting applied because '.navbar-default' is the parent and then it goes to the child, as '.navbar-nav' is the child of it. Since it contains two classes so it is having higher priority whereas in the latter the css applied, was with '.navbar-account', which has a lower priority than that of the other.

Comment: No problem @Harry, I have gone through your answer and it does contains much more info than that of mines. Upvote from me for your answer. Happy coding friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following style:

```
.navbar-account>li>a:first-child{
     color:#E84c4c;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer might get flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .navbar-account > li > a:active{
    #give your style
    }
```

[Check this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5fv5.png)

U can use this button to show your style on active ,hover ,focus.